# I keep getting the error: "Git must be installed and in your PATH" when installing PHP

Tags: php, git, macos, homebrew, macos-monterey

I'm trying to install php on my Mac running Monterey. I try to install it using brew and I get this error: **Error: Git must be installed and in your PATH!**

I've tried brew doctor and brew upgrade and they give the same error. Any help would be great.

Here's the full code below:

```
andrews-mbp:OSX-Messages-Exporter-master andrew$ brew install php@7.4
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/version.rb:366:in `initialize': Version value must be a string; got a NilClass () (TypeError)
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac/version.rb:23:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac.rb:18:in `new'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac.rb:18:in `version'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac.rb:52:in `prerelease?'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os.rb:19:in `<module:OS>'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:21:in `require_relative'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:21:in `<main>'
Error: Git must be installed and in your PATH!
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/version.rb:366:in `initialize': Version value must be a string; got a NilClass () (TypeError)
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac/version.rb:23:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac.rb:18:in `new'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac.rb:18:in `version'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac.rb:52:in `prerelease?'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os.rb:19:in `<module:OS>'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:21:in `require_relative'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:21:in `<main>'
andrews-mbp:OSX-Messages-Exporter-master andrew$
```

Comment: Do you have git installed and in your path?

Comment: How can I check that? I tried git install and I got the same error.

Comment: `echo $PATH`    also are you on an old macos?

Comment: same problem, appeared after migration of old account, doing it with another newly created user did not solve the issue

Answer (score 2):

You maybe missing xcode-select tools. try the below command.

```
xcode-select --install
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be linked to rosetta [unable to knit pdf on M2 Mac: pandoc error Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/quarto/bin/tools/pandoc: Bad CPU type in executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74979639/unable-to-knit-pdf-on-m2-mac-pandoc-error-applications-rstudio-app-contents-res)

I did run `/usr/sbin/softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license`and things were fixed.