# unable to knit pdf on M2 Mac: pandoc error Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/quarto/bin/tools/pandoc: Bad CPU type in executable

Tags: r-markdown, rstudio, pandoc

I get this error

```
sh: /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/quarto/bin/tools/pandoc: Bad CPU type in executable

Error in strsplit(info, "\n")[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
In addition: Warning message:
In system(paste(shQuote(path), "--version"), intern = TRUE) :
  running command ''/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/quarto/bin/tools/pandoc' --version' had status 126
```

MAC OS: 13.1

Macbook Air M2

Rstudio: 2022.12.0+353

Can someone please help. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like the pandoc built in with latest Rstudio is incompatible with 
MAC OS: 13.1
Macbook Air M2

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @guna, I followed [the GitHub link](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/12512) to find the solution. What I needed to do was run the following code in the Terminal:

```
/usr/sbin/softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license
```

After this, the knitting started working fine again. No RStudio or R restart needed.

Comment: spent a couple of days trying to find a solution. This works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like Ventura upgrade removed Rosetta 2

Fix; install Rosetta 2

More here;

https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/12512